# How to save data from the serial port to the mysql database with C programming

Tags: mysql, c, arduino

I want to save temperature data from arduino to the mysql database. Arduino with the MySQL database connected via a USB serial port. To save data from Arduino to MySQL, I use the C programming language by reading the Arduino serial port. The problem is that the data are stored into mysql not the same as what is displayed on the monitor serial arduino.

Data from Arduino in the serial monitor are:

```
26.37
26.27
26.38
26.50
...
```

Programs reading from serial ports in C are:

```
    char TempChar;
    DWORD NoBytesRead;

    char query[100];
    char INSERT_DATA[] = "INSERT INTO lm35 (id, temp) VALUES (%d,%f)";
do{
    ReadFile(hComm,&TempChar,sizeof(TempChar),&NoBytesRead,NULL);
    sprintf(query, INSERT_DATA, 00, (float)TempChar);

     if (mysql_query(conn,query))
      {
       printf(" Error: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
       return 0;
    }

      printf("OK \n");
}while(!kbhit());

 CloseHandle(hComm);
 mysql_close(conn);
```

Fields and data types in tables in mysql are:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| temp  | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Data stored in a table in the mysql database are:

```
+------+------+
| id   | temp |
+------+------+
| 1500 |   50 |
| 1499 |   10 |
| 1498 |   13 |
| 1497 |   56 |
| 1496 |   56 |
+------+------+
```

How to save  temp(termperature) data to the mysql database? Why not the same temperature data on the Arduino serial monitor that is stored on MySQL?

Comment: The code is not error, but the data stored is not the same as the Arduino data (serial port)

Answer (score 2):

You can't just cast with `(float)` on a character buffer, you need to use something like [`atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof):

```
sprintf(query, INSERT_DATA, 00, atof(TempChar));
```

You're getting the ASCII value for your digits, like `'2'` is `50` and `'8'` is `56`. `10` and `13` are newline and carriage return, respectively. It looks like you'll need to read in not just one character, but a series of characters while waiting for a CRLF terminator.

It's likely you'll need to use something like `fgets()` instead of grabbing single characters, or if you do, you'll need to create a buffer for your numbers. You want to read **each line of text**, not individual characters if you can swing it.

Note since your `id` is auto-increment, don't specify it in the `INSERT` statement, just omit that column and associated value. MySQL will auto-populate it.

Comment: If you use atof, i.e. convert from char to float it will appear: **Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 4.517 s**

Comment: Looks like your `main()` function didn't `return` something.

Comment: Sorry I mean is If I use atof, i.e. convert from char to float it will appear: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) execution time : 4.517 s

Comment: The key is `atof()` takes a `char*` C-string, not just individual characters. You need to read in an entire line into a NUL (0-byte) delimited C-string buffer and parse that. If your program compiles you don't have enough warnings turned on (e.g. engage `-Wall`) because you can't pass `char` to a `char*` argument.

Comment: Yes, how can I make C program code to change the TempChar char to float? Where can I see a tutorial about that, because it's been on Google but haven't found it yet.

Comment: What functions besides `ReadFile` do you have? Is there a `ReadFileLine`?